# Получить залогиненого пользователя Laravel

Tags: laravel

У меня стандартная аутентификация, в контроллере получаю таким образом и все выводит

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
  $user = Auth::user();
  dump($user);
```

Так же у меня есть контроллер который прописан в api.php и работает со списком продуктов

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v2', 'as' => 'api.', 'namespace' => 'Api\V2'], function () {

    // Products
    Route::apiResource('products', 'ProductController');
});
```

Как мне в этом контроллере получить залогиненного пользователя ? `Auth::user()` возвращает null

По сути мне только id нужно получить текущего залогиненного пользователя

Код контроллера

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V2;

use App\Http\Resources\BaseAllResource;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Filters\UsersFilter;
use App\Base;
use App\User;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class BaseController extends Controller
{

    public function test(Request $request){

        $user = Auth::user();
        dump($user);

    }


}
```

Comment: скорее всего мидлвари авторизации нет. покажите класс ProductController. В нем есть `$this->middleware("auth");`?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос кодом контроллера, а где должен быть код авторизации ?

Comment: Вставляю в конструктор, но он редиректит на другую страницу даже при залогиненом пользователе

Comment: Получить залогиненого пользователя на апи роуте, что то странное или я что то путаю, пасспорт или JWT разве не должны там работать по токенам, как на апи придет запрос от Auth user если апи не предназначен для этого?

Answer (score 2):

В файле **app\Http\Kernel.php** добавите в переменную $middleware путь:

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

Comment: Получается двойная авторизация, при попытки получить продукты залогиненому пользователю приходится опять авторизироваться... можно этого избежать ?

Comment: Я не вижу весь принцип как  у вас происходит запрос к API но если пользователь уже авторизирован на вашем сайте то повторно данные запрашивать недолжно.

Comment: А вкратце что я сделал добавив этот путь в переменную $middleware ?

Comment: Глобально дали доступ к сессиям через которые и происходит авторизация пользователя

При этом вам также необходимо в контролере BaseController в конструктор добавить $this->middleware("auth");
Пример:
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();        
        $this->middleware("auth");
    }